# Liferay IDE maxpermsize setting not picked up

Tags: java, tomcat7, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I have an issue with the Liferay IDE(on Mac OS) not picking up the -XX:MaxPermSize=512m setting in the setenv.sh in the tomcat bundle folder liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp2/tomcat-7.0.42/bin.

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false -Duser.timezone=GMT -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m "
```

The maxpermsize setting is picked up[ when running the Liferay bundle from command line (./startup.sh).

However, maxpermsize setting is not picked up when running the server from the Liferay IDE.

I confirmed the above behavior by running visualVM.

There does not seem to be anyway to modify the JVM settings from the Liferay IDE on server properties or I can not find it easily.

Does anyone know how to override maxpermsize from the Liferay IDE?

Any insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double click on Liferay server environment.
[image: Step 1]

It will open up window where Memory args can be set as in image below.
The process to set Memory arguments should be same in Mac and other systems in liferay IDE/liferay developer studio.

[image: Step 2]

Comment: Thanks Haris - the double click on the server was the key!